# Jquery NivoSlider Slider is not working $('#slider').nivoSlider(); is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, slider

I am using nivo jquery image slider in my asp.net application, but after page load its not changing the images and only showing "loading.gif" image, on jquery debugging i am  getting error message : $('#slider').nivoSlider(); is not a function.

```
   <link href="css/NivoSlideThemes/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="css/NivoSlideThemes/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"  />
    <script src="js/menu/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    <script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
        </script>
          <style>   

            .theme-default #slider {
                margin:1px auto 0 auto;
                width:674px; /* Make sure your images are the same size */
                height:311px; /* Make sure your images are the same size */
            }
            .theme-pascal.slider-wrapper,
            .theme-orman.slider-wrapper {
               /* margin-top:150px;  */
            }

            .clear {
                clear:both;
            }

      </style> 

       <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default"> 
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/cfgSliderImages/1.gif" alt="" />
                <img src="images/cfgSliderImages/2.gif" alt="" title="Solar Power" />
                <img src="images/cfgSliderImages/3.gif" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" />
                <img src="images/cfgSliderImages/4.gif" alt=""   title="#htmlcaption" />
            </div>
            <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
                <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the proper JS files for the slider are loading?

Comment: are you using two sliders on the one page? Can you post the html markup for the other one aswell? If you are using the same initialisation code for both then it will probably break it since they both have the same id (`#slider`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

Maybe there is a conflict with jQuery, so use `.noConflict()`:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function () {
    j('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this problem when I'm using Visual Studio every now and then. Instead of referencing the scripts in the `body`, I add them in the `head`.

```
<head>
    <link href="css/NivoSlideThemes/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link href="css/NivoSlideThemes/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"  />
    <script src="js/menu/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    <script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

This has especially been a problem with jQuery as well.

However, you need to put your javascript in the document ready function:

```
// When the page is ready to be manipulated
$(function() {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
});
```